# Web RTC Server is running in localhost only

Tags: webrtc, apprtcdemo, apprtc, openwebrtcdemo

I've configured Web RTC sever in my PC. It's working with http://localhost:8080 But this server is not working with the IP address in another machines.

I've referred Web RTC Server with this [URL](https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc).

Answer (score 1):

It might be a certificate problem.
For Chrome you need to host your website on secure http (https) and your webrtc websocket needs to be also secured (wss). Localhost is an exception for this. You might try to test with Firefox as that doesn't require wss.

Comment: I've tested in Firefox Browser. But not loading. Even in my PC also when I test with the IP address, it's not loading, but when I tested with the localhost it's loading.

Comment: We need to Setup any TURN/ICE server and a signaling server for our Own server @Istvan

Comment: If you are testing on localhost, the STUN and TURN can't be a problem. You can just disable these by passing an empty array for ICE.

Answer (score 0):

try start with mentioning --host=your local ip address